# Linked list is missing two elements Why Output is 10 12 32 34 35 44 55 56 57 64 72 80 120 Last two elements are missing

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm very new to Data Structure
Why Output is 10 12 32 34 35 44 55 56 57 64 72 80 120
Last two elements are missing(130,156)
The two element are from second linked list

I'm very new to Data Structure
Why Output is 10 12 32 34 35 44 55 56 57 64 72 80 120
Last two elements are missing(130,156)

The two element are from second linked list

I'm new Please Help me

Here is my Code:

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int data, Node next){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
     Node() {}
}
 class Main {
     public static void printData(String msg, Node head){
         Node ptr = head;
         System.out.print(msg);
         while (ptr != null){
             System.out.print(ptr.data + "->");
             ptr = ptr.next;
         }
         System.out.println("null");
     }
     public static void mergeList(Node l1, Node l2) {

         Node TempNode = new Node();
         Node CurrentNode = TempNode;

        while(l1 != null && l2 != null){
            if (l1.data < l2.data){
                CurrentNode.next = l1;
                l1 = l1.next;
            }else{
                CurrentNode.next = l2;
                l2 = l2.next;
            }
            CurrentNode = CurrentNode.next;
            System.out.print(" " + CurrentNode.data);

        }
         if (l1 != null){
             System.out.println( " " + l1.data);
         }if(l2 != null){
             System.out.println(" " + l2.data);
         }


     }





    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] keys = {10,32,35,44,55,64,72,80};
        int[] keys2 = {12,34,56,57,120,130,156};


        Node c = null;
        Node d = null;



        for(int i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1 ){
            c = new Node(keys[i],c);
        }
        for(int i = keys2.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1){
            d = new Node(keys2[i],d);
        }



        printData("List c: ",c);
        printData("List d: ",d);


        mergeList(c,d);

    }
}
```

Comment: if (l1 != null){
             System.out.println( " " + l1.data);
         }if(l2 != null){
             System.out.println(" " + l2.data);
         }
This will print just the current node's data, not the next ones.

Comment: Because you stop merging when you fully consumed one of the two input lists. You need to add the remaining elements of the non-consumed list to the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that your code assumes that after the `while` loop has finished there will be at most 1 more element to print. But this is not true. `l1` might refer to a node that may not be the *last* node -- there may be several nodes following it, that also need printing. If `l1` is null, then the above can be true for `l2`.

So replace this:

```
if (l1 != null){
    System.out.println( " " + l1.data);
}if(l2 != null){
    System.out.println(" " + l2.data);
}
```

with this:

```
while (l1 != null) {
    System.out.print( " " + l1.data);
    l1 = l1.next;
}
while (l2 != null) {
    System.out.print(" " + l2.data);
    l2 = l2.next;
}
System.out.println();
```

### Other remark

Not related to your question, but the name `mergeList` actually suggests that it would return a new list that is the merge of the two given lists. But it does not do so. It only prints "as if" there is such a list. But no list is created. You may want to do something about that.